# Change on column based on any previous values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, radix

I have a dataframe like so:

```
foo <- c(rep(FALSE, 5), TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4))
rank_order <- seq(11,20)

df <- data.frame(rank_order = as.numeric(rank_order),
                 foo = foo)
```

What I'd like to do is add one to every value of `rank_order` following a row where `df$foo == TRUE`.  That means `rank_order` should look like this:

```
rank_order_target <- c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
```

It's easy enough to change one value of `rank_order`, with `lag` looking at one previous value of `foo` (like below), but how do I look at all previous values of `foo`?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(rank_order_new = case_when(lag(foo, default = FALSE) == TRUE ~ rank_order + 1,
                          TRUE ~ rank_order))
   rank_order   foo rank_order_new
1          11 FALSE             11
2          12 FALSE             12
3          13 FALSE             13
4          14 FALSE             14
5          15 FALSE             15
6          16  TRUE             16
7          17 FALSE             18
8          18 FALSE             18
9          19 FALSE             19
10         20 FALSE             20
```

Either a `base` solution, or something `tidyverse` would be helpful.

Comment: Did you meant to add 1 for each row or only when foo is TRUE?

Comment: I'd like to add one to each row after the row where foo is TRUE

Comment: I guess `rank_order_target` is your expected?

Comment: @akrun Yes, but I can't count - I've edited `rank_order_target`.  You had it the first time, with `rank_order + cumsum(foo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(new = rank_order + cumsum(foo))
```